# How do I assign an input from one python script to be an input in another script as well

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I currently have two different python scripts. The first one converts parquet files to xlsx and the second is really just trying to build a gui to be able to run the first script.**

Here is the first script:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pyarrow
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
file = input("What file would you like to convert from parquet to csv? ")
df1 = pd.read_parquet(file)
df = df1.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
dirout = input("Where would you like the xlsx file to be output to?")
name = input("What would you like to call the ouput file?" )
cfile = os.path.join(dirout, name + "." + "xlsx")
df.to_excel(cfile)
```

In this second script I would like the user to input txt that would feed file, name and dirout. Is that possible?

```
import os
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Convertor")
#Sets the size of the window
window.geometry('550x400')

#Adds a header to the window and configures the size 
lbl = Label(window, text="Convert Parquet to CSV", font=("Arial Bold", 18))

#Configures where the label message will appear
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

#adds an input text message
txt = Entry(window,width = 30)
txt.grid(column=3, row=3)

txt = Entry(window,width = 30)
txt.grid(column=4, row=4)
def clicked():
    os.system('python ParquetToCsv.py')
#Adding a button
btn = Button(window, text="Convert", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=6, row = 6)

#The mainloop causes the window to remain open until someone interacts with it
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn your first script into a function with arguments for the variables you want to pass:

```
def myfunc(f, n, dir):
   file = f
   df1 = pd.read_parquet(file)
   df = df1.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
   dirout = dir
   name = n
   cfile = os.path.join(dirout, name + "." + "xlsx")
   df.to_excel(cfile)
```

Then import the function into the other script and call it passing the arguments:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from myutils import myfunc

window = Tk()
window.title("Convertor")
#Sets the size of the window
window.geometry('550x400')

#Adds a header to the window and configures the size 
lbl = Label(window, text="Convert Parquet to CSV", font=("Arial Bold", 18))

#Configures where the label message will appear
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

#adds an input text message
txt_name = Entry(window,width = 30)
txt.grid(column=3, row=3)

txt_file = Entry(window,width = 30)
txt.grid(column=4, row=4)

txt_dir = Entry(window,width = 30)
txt.grid(column=4, row=4)
def clicked():
    os.system('python ParquetToCsv.py')
#Adding a button
btn = Button(window, text="Convert", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=6, row = 6)

#The mainloop causes the window to remain open until someone interacts with it
window.mainloop()

# Call function passing the arguments
myfunc(txt_file, txt_name, txt_dir)
```